# Is there any way to read past intels?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

In Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3, Intel shows up before a match starts or whenever anything starts. I want to know if there is a way to reread any of that, or do I need to wait until it shows up again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no other way to see it.

"During every mission if you press the start button there will be a tally of how many pieces of intel there are in the mission and how many of them you have collected. It should show on the bottom right hand corner of the start menu. Other than that, there is no way to find out which intel you're missing."
[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/995751-call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3/answers/299769-how-do-i-find-out-which-intel-im-missing)

Comment: I think they're referring to [this](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120622074104/callofduty/images/a/a6/Loading_Screen_Vortex_MW3.jpg) intel, which is unfortunately has the same name as the hidden intel you find in single-player missions. I've looked around and there doesn't appear to be a text dump of all possible messages on that screen within a quick Google search's reach.